# What is the IIS equivalent of mod_wsgi's WSGIScriptAlias?

Tags: iis, iis-6, python, django

I'm trying to get Django running on IIS 6 using pyisapie and I'm having some trouble. I have pyisapie working on IIS, but it only works if I specify the full url to a specific python script like so:

```
http://localhost/sample/test.py
```

I have PyISAPIe.dll set as a wildcard application map for the virtual directory where my application lives.  The part that I don't understand is how do I tell PyISAPIe.dll which python script to execute when I hit my virtual directory from the url?

I want to be able to navigate to

```
http://localhost/sample/any/thing/that/I/want/right/here
```

and have test.py be executed. If I try the 2nd url now, I get a 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to specify an existing file.py, then you probably put in the configuration of the Virtual Directory on IIS6 an Application extension with PyISAPIe.dll instead of a Wildcard Application map (lower pane) in the Application Configuration screen. 
For me it works now.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/iiscgihowto.html
See above link as well.
Have no experience here but thought that IIS supported CGI therefor why not wsgi?

Comment: I have wsgi working on IIS already, but it only works when I hit a python script from the URL... I don't know how to configure IIS to have a WSGIScriptAlias like mod_wsgi for Apache.